# Create mount point on read-only filesystem for fstab to mount

Tags: linux, mount, fstab, openwrt, read-only

I'm running TomatoUSB on a Broadcom-based broadband router. I have a busybox-style shell available to me. I'd like to have a partition on the attached USB hard drive mounted in /data under the root filesystem. The issue is that the root filesystem is read-only and I can't seem to create the mount point.

The device in question is /dev/sda3, created as an ext2 filesystem with label "Data", which Tomato can automatically mount as /mnt/Data if it is told to. A pre-existing mount point of /opt can successfully attach to /dev/sda1 automatically so I think this should be possible, i.e. I just need to have the mount point created and have it survive a reboot?

Here's my /etc/fstab:

```
#device Mountpoint FStype Options Dump Pass#
LABEL=Optware /opt ext2 rw,noatime 1 1
LABEL=Swap none swap sw 0 0
LABEL=Data /data ext2 rw,noatime 1 1
```

As above, a Linux swap partition (/dev/sda2) also mounts and is made active at boot.

I wonder if an 'nvram' command would do what I need. Or a command under the startup section of the scripts GUI, which will at some point in the bootup do what's needed...not sure if it will prepend fstab execution however.

Comment: Pardon me for not understanding. What are you trying to do that cannot be achieved with the built-in tomato interface? Mount to /data instead of /mnt? http://www.society9.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/tomato-nas-usb-support-1024x791.png

Comment: Yes, mounting to /data. For example, if there's an application that uses a hard-coded path which cannot be changed.